# the relationship between different definitions of Hardy Littlewood maximal inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If we denote 
\begin{align}
Hf   &= \sup\left\{\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy\right\}, \\
H^*f &= \sup\left\{\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B} |f(y)|dy, B\text{ is a ball containing } x\right\} \end{align}
How do we show that $Hf\leq H^*f\leq2^n Hf\ $?

This is from Wheeden's book: Measure and Integral.

Comment: Maybe you mean $(Hf)(x)$ and $(H^* f)(x)$ so that $x$ becomes a bound variable?

Comment: Yes, x is the variable. I forgot to say that f is integrable in R^n, that is how the 2 ^ n comes out in the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Hf\le H^*f$ is clear, since the set of balls centered at $x$ is a subset of the set of balls containing $x$.

For the other inequality, let $B$ be a ball containing $x$ and let $r$ be its radius. Then $B\subset B(x,2r)$ and
$$
\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B} |f(y)|\,dy\le\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B(x,2r)} |f(y)|\,dy=\frac{2^n}{m(B(x,2r))}\int_{B(x,2r)} |f(y)|\,dy.
$$